# Numpy: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, face-recognition

```
@shared_task()
def get_encodings_and_compare_with_friends(pk):
    photo = Photo.objects.get(pk=pk)
    persons = Person.objects.all()
    image = face_recognition.load_image_file(photo.image)
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(image)
    for encoding in encodings:
        for person in persons:
            person_encoding=np.loads(person.face_encodings)
            if face_recognition.compare_faces(encoding,person_encoding):
                tag = Tags(photo= photo, tag = person.pk, is_user=True)
                tag.save()
    return
```

I am trying to load face_encodings from database where it is stored as binary blob. Then this encoding and encoding from the image is compared with a support vector machine to find is they are equal. But I am getting this error as mentioned in the title.

This is the library I am using `https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/`

traceback

```
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 69, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 494, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 454, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 491, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/generics.py", line 192, in post
    return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/rest_framework/mixins.py", line 21, in create
    self.perform_create(serializer)
  File "/home/firefly/SourceCode/Inshare/gallery/views.py", line 21, in perform_create
    get_encodings_and_compare_with_friends(photo.pk)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/local.py", line 191, in __call__
    return self._get_current_object()(*a, **kw)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/celery/app/task.py", line 380, in __call__
    return self.run(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/firefly/SourceCode/Inshare/gallery/tasks.py", line 29, in get_encodings_and_compare_with_friends
    if face_recognition.compare_faces(encoding,person_encoding):
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 203, in compare_faces
    return list(face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding_to_check) <= tolerance)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 70, in face_distance
    return np.linalg.norm(face_encodings - face_to_compare, axis=1)
  File "/home/firefly/.local/share/virtualenvs/Inshare-0sncsKh-/lib/python3.5/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py", line 2287, in norm
    return sqrt(add.reduce(s, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims))
numpy.core._internal.AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

Comment: the error is traced back to face_recognition.compare_faces line

Comment: If you read the [docstring](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/657e98bfa2f2b55da4449c8271a108bf4f193e05/face_recognition/api.py#L203-L210) of `compare_faces`, the first argument is supposed to be a *list* of face encodings. It looks as though you're passing a single encoding.  It would be helpful if you included the entire traceback in your question.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Just added the trace back

Comment: I suspect that this is a bug/missing feature in `face_recognition`, and it should be passing `axis=-1`

Comment: If your problem is not solved which I guess is not solved
what I did is take the first element of encoding as follows
encodeTest = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgTest)[0]
Now check whether it works or not

Answer (score 2):

```
face_recognition.compare_faces([encoding],person_encoding)
```

giving encoding as list solves the problem

Comment: I did the same 
results = face_recognition.compare_faces([encodeBasic],encodeTest)

output
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Basic.py", line 20, in <module>
    results = face_recognition.compare_faces([encodeBasic],encodeTest)
  packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 226, in compare_faces
    return list(face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding_to_check) <= tolerance)
  packages/face_recognition/api.py", line 75, in face_distance
    return np.linalg.norm(face_encodings - face_to_compare, axis=1)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'list'

Answer (score 0):

```
np.array(face_recognition.face_encodings(image))
```

You have to give it a numpy array as known encodings (first parameter of compare_faces function) because the distance function cannot subtract two lists. and the first list should be a list of encodings to compare so @ilovecse answer is correct. but if you are using the latest version of face_recognition library, then mine will work.